# PrimeFaces menubar scroll blocks submenu

Tags: css, jsf, primefaces

I am developing a simple CRUD web app. Tables that users want to edit are placed in a menu, where users can select them and than edit them. As it turns out not all users have big monitors like I do so here I stumbled upon my problem. When monitor or browser window is not big enough to display the whole menu, menu gets a vertical scroller and as long as menu has scroller, submenus are not visible (hidden below). You do however get a horizontal scroller but that is not very practical.

I know that it is a CSS problem but I've never been an expert in CSS. I know the basics to tweek my webpage here and there but this is beyond my CSS-knowledge. I've searched the web and found that people have similar problems with panels. I've tried their solutions but it didn't work on my case.

All of you web/CSS experts out there, please help me. I know in the past I've spent plenty of hours resolving similar CSS problems and I'd really appreciate if someone can solve it faster.

I've tried to post a picture of the problem but I don't have enough reputation points so I'll just post code instead:

```
<h:form>
    <p:menubar>  
        <p:submenu label="Menu 1" icon="ui-icon-document">  
            <p:submenu label="Choice 1" >
                 <p:menuitem value="SubChoice 1" url="#" />  
                 <p:menuitem value="SubChoice 2" url="#" />  
                 <p:menuitem value="SubChoice 3" url="#" />  
                 <p:menuitem value="SubChoice 4" url="#" />  
            </p:submenu>
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 2" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 3" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 4" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 5" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 6" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 7" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 8" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 9" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 10" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 11" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 12" url="#" /> 
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 7" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 8" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 9" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 10" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 11" url="#" />  
            <p:menuitem value="Choice 12" url="#" /> 
        </p:submenu>  
        <p:submenu label="Menu 2" icon="ui-icon-document" >  
             <p:menuitem value="Choice 1" url="#" />  
        </p:submenu>  
    </p:menubar>
</h:form>
```

You can replicate the issue if you resize the browser to the height that the whole menu cannot be displayed anymore and you see a vertical scroll. Then if you go on a submenu it will no longer be visible.

Probably the most sensible thing would be to divide this menu entries into some kind of groups, but the customer wants it like this so I don't have much choice...

I'm using Primefaces 4.0, JBoss 7.1.1, NetBeans 7.4, Chrome 32

Let me know if you need any more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the Menubar items are a bit much, the scrollbar would appear.

In order to maintain the case of the submenu of a submenu, I had to override the runtime styling which is done by `PrimeFaces.widget.Menubar` javascript class.

After your form include this script.

```
<script>
   PrimeFaces.widget.Menubar.prototype.activate = function(b) {
       this.highlight(b);
       var a = b.children("ul.ui-menu-child");
       if (a.length == 1) {
           b.parent().css('display', 'table')
           this.showSubmenu(b, a)           
       } else{
           b.parent().css('display', 'block')
       }
   }
</script>
```

A small working example can be found on [github](https://github.com/hatemalimam/DailyLab/blob/master/src/main/webapp/menubar/main.xhtml).
And an [online Demo](http://jsf.hatemalimam.com/DailyLab/faces/menubar/main.xhtml).

**Note:** `display : 'table'` is not supported in IE7 and earlier. IE8 requires a !DOCTYPE. IE9 supports the values.

Hope this Helps.

Comment: It works. And I thought i'd have to make up excuses to the customer :) Thank you Hatem.

Comment: Although this question is a bit older now, but does this still work with PF 5.x? If I try the solution, my menu gets funny additional whitespace lines and the submenu in the scrolled list doesn't even appear. Is there a respective issue in the primefaces bugtracking? [edit] I had a typo in my search, found the issue: https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/120